# elastic search 5.1 why stored_fields does not return asked field?

Tags: elasticsearch, sense

In Elastic Search 5.1 I am making basic request with stored_fields body argument  (new name for old fields argument) for retrieving the value of a specific field.

But my request give no field value in answer except _index, _type, _id and _score

I Give you sample for context:

I create index and mapping with:

```
 PUT /base_well
    {
        "mappings": {
            "person": {
                   "properties": {
                       "first_name":{
                           "type": "string"
                       },
                         "last_name":{
                           "type": "string"
                       },
                       "age":{
                           "type": "long"
                       }
                   }
            }
        }
    }
```

I populate :

```
  POST /base_well/person
        {
            "first_name":"James",
            "last_name" : "Mopo",
            "Age" : 21
        }

    POST /base_well/person
    {
        "first_name":"Polo",
        "last_name" : "Rodriguez",
        "Age" : 36
    }

    POST /base_well/person
    {
        "first_name":"Marc Aurelien",
        "last_name" : "Poisson",
        "Age" : 26
    }

    POST /base_well/person
    {
        "first_name":"Mustapha",
        "last_name" : "Bulutu M'Bo",
        "Age" : 47
    }
```

I do my request with:

```
    POST  /base_well/person/_search
{
   "stored_fields": ["first_name"]

}
```

And it give me an answere  without the requested field fiest_person:

```
{
   "took": 4,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 8,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "base_well",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "AVlFYzihcR_Z5VPUXUCL",
            "_score": 1
         },
         {
            "_index": "base_well",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "AVlFiv3acR_Z5VPUXUCa",
            "_score": 1
         },
         {
            "_index": "base_well",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "AVlFiwUKcR_Z5VPUXUCb",
            "_score": 1
         },
         {
            "_index": "base_well",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "AVlFYx2LcR_Z5VPUXUCI",
            "_score": 1
         },
         {
            "_index": "base_well",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "AVlFYyhScR_Z5VPUXUCJ",
            "_score": 1
         },
         {
            "_index": "base_well",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "AVlFYzIJcR_Z5VPUXUCK",
            "_score": 1
         },
         {
            "_index": "base_well",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "AVlFivgzcR_Z5VPUXUCZ",
            "_score": 1
         },
         {
            "_index": "base_well",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "AVlFiw2qcR_Z5VPUXUCc",
            "_score": 1
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Anybody could explain me to do it and how it works please?

Comment: Do you see the source if you add `"_source": true` to your query?

Comment: no, maybe it is the answere

Comment: I'm puzzled because you mention `stored_fields` in your question but I don't see that anywhere in your query.

Comment: maybe i did a mistake I check

Comment: sorry I did a wrong copy paste :( , it was stuppid and a no-sens thank you for having told me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, the document fields are not stored, i.e. in your mapping you don't specify `store: true` for each of them.

Hence, `"stored_fields": ["first_name"]` will not be able to return the `first_name` field since it's not stored.

You can use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) instead and specify `"_source": ["first_name"]` in your query, that will work.

Comment: And for query string it will looks like: `&_source=field_1,field_2`

Comment: To me, the `_source` only returns the fields defined in the mapping config. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: _source will return whatever was sent in the source document and has not been filtered out either at indexing time or search time